# How to save a multidimensional matrix in separated files for each dimension

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, export, tensors

I need to export to a file a multidimensional matrix, each dimension to a file. 
For example:

```
A = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 1, 4}}, {{2, 1, 4}, {1, 5, 3}, {5, 5, 
    5}}, {{1, 5, 3}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 3}}};
```

[image]

After

```
Export["namefile.dat", A, "Table"]
```

The `namefile.dat` has

```
{1, 2, 3}   {4, 5, 6}   {2, 1, 4}
{2, 1, 4}   {1, 5, 3}   {5, 5, 5}
{1, 5, 3}   {9, 8, 7}   {4, 5, 3}
```

I would like to save 3 files 
`X.dat` with content

```
1 4 2
2 1 5
1 9 4
```

`Y.dat` with content

```
2 5 1
1 5 5
5 8 8
```

and `Z.dat`

```
3 6 4
4 3 5
3 7 3
```

I know this is probably easy to solve just by looking at the Mathematica reference. However, I have not found a solution after testing some commands and surfing the web.

Comment: You could try something like `MapIndexed[Export["file" <> Apply[IntegerString, #2] <> ".dat", #, "Table"] &, Transpose[A, {2, 3, 1}]]`

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Thank you. Your solution works fine.